# What is the difference between a SVN server and a HTTP server

Tags: svn, protocols

On my subversion client (cornerstone), when connecting to a new SVN repository I have 3 options: File repository, HTTP Server and SVN Server.

Is the difference only in the protocol used to communicate ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  SVN can be accessed through HTTP/WebDAV with the mod_dav_svn Apache module.  Other than the protocol difference, it supports the same operations.

You can read more about this configuration in the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache).

Comment: PS always remember to access the newest version of this document, or rather depending on the SVN version you're currently using.
The link above leads to SVN version **1.5** manual, whereas the newest available one is **[1.7](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache)**. Currently, **[1.8](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache)** is in draft stage with 1.9 not even available yet.

Answer (score 3):

The (free online) [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html) has a good description of the [different server protocols](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html) and [recommendations](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.recommendations) for when each should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Yes protocol should be the only difference. See the section titled http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_(software) 'repository access'.

If your concerned about security try to use the https if you choose the http server option or the svn+ssh protocol if you choose the svn server option.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the protocol, but if you choose HTTP, you do have some extra possibilities, i.e. you can access your repository with a web browser or WebDAV client. So strictly spoken you don't need to install svn client software to consult the repository (although as soon as you want to do anything useful you obviously do need a real svn client).